# count numbers associated with category in list

Tags: python

I have a list like this

```
GroupID,Number
yellow,1
yellow,2
tan,0
blue,1
black,2
black,3
```

What I want is this

```
GroupID,Number
yellow,3
tan, 0
blue,1
black,5
```

So I want to add the numbers associated with each groupID.

This is what I got, but have difficulty with the result statement:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
f = open("metal_modules.csv","r")
sheet = f.readlines()
#print sheet
for line in sheet[1:]:
#print line
spl = line.strip().split(",")
#print spl[1]
name = spl[0]
d[name].append(spl[1])

outfile = open("out.txt","w")
result = ""
for v in d.values():
     result = #here I need to sum the number in column two for each key in    the dictionary#
#print result
outfile.write(result)
f.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: is that the order import for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep it simple

```
result = ""
for group in d:
    result += "%s, %s\n" % (group, sum(n for n in d[group]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below if the order won't be an  important issue for you.

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('infile') as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    h = f.readline()
    m = f.readlines()
    for i in m:
        s = i.rstrip().split(',')
        d[s[0]].append(s[1])
with open('outfile', 'w') as w:
        w.write(h)
        for i in d.items():
            w.write(i[0]+","+str(sum(map(int,i[1])))+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

```
with open("metal_modules.csv","r") as f:
  sheet = f.readlines()
  counter = {}
  for line in sheet[1:]:
    k,v = line.split(",")
    if k in counter:
      counter[k] += int(v)
    else:
      counter[k] = int(v)

with open("out.txt","w") as outfile:
  result = "GroupID,Number\n"
  for item in counter:
    result += "%s,%s\n" % (item,counter[item])
  outfile.write(result.strip())
```